# I want to increase label's number by 10 on button click

Tags: c#

sorry if this question has been solved before, but it was solved in another way, i want when the user click the button the label's number increase by 10 The code i'm using is:

```
int  correct;

private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    correct++;
}
```

But it increases it's number by 1, is it possible to increase it by 10?

Comment: Like this: correct += 10

Comment: Thank you! Worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add 10 use the statement:

```
correct += 10;
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the **+=** operation and set the label content

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    correct += 10;
    myLabel.Content = correct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like: (correct variable should be numeric type)

```
correct += 10;
```

or

```
correct = correct + 10;
```